# Angularjs to download a private video file and play from s3 bucket

Tags: angularjs, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to download a video file from s3 bucket and show it in my angularjs app. I am trying to do it using AWS Node.js but not able to do it. Please help me

Sample Code

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update(
  {
    accessKeyId: ".. your key ..",
    secretAccessKey: ".. your secret key ..",
  }
);
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
s3.getObject(
  { Bucket: "my-bucket", Key: "path/to/videofile" },
  function (error, data) {
    if (error != null) {
      alert("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
    } else {
      alert("Loaded " + data.ContentLength + " bytes");
      // do something with data.Body
    }
  }
);
```

I am able to get the data but not know how to show it, data is an object

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer, I need to Body element then convert it to base64 encoded data. Code below

```
    var d = s3.getObject(params,function (error, data) {
      if (error != null) {
        console.log("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
      } else {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.learningVideo = "data:video/mp4;base64," + encode(data.Body);
      }
   })
```

And for encode method

```
function encode(data)
  {
    var str = data.reduce(function(a,b){ return a+String.fromCharCode(b) },'');
    return btoa(str).replace(/.{76}(?=.)/g,'$&\n');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you're looking for will be in the `Body` of the response object you received.

Per [AWS SDK documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property), this is what you might expect to see in `Body`:

> Body — (Buffer, Typed Array, Blob, String, ReadableStream) Object data.